# How can I make the system call write() print to the screen?

Tags: c, linux, system-calls

For my OS class I'm supposed to implement Linux's cat using only system calls (no printf)

Reading [this reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ostream/write/) I found it being used to print to a file. I guess I should manipulate ofstream.

In the example appears: `ofstream outfile ("new.txt",ofstream::binary);`

How can I make it write to the screen?

**EDIT: I realized this write() is part of iostream library, is this the same as the int write (int fd, char *buf , int size) system call?**

Comment: And don't forget that Linux cat is GNU cat and sports 11 non-ignored command line options ;-).http://linux.die.net/man/1/cat

Comment: You've tagged this as `C` but you're talking about and have linked to `C++` classes. Is this supposed to be C, or C++? Re your edit - I wouldn't consider iostream to be allowed, given "only system calls", only things like `man 2 write`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, `std::ostream::write` is not the same as the `write` system call. It does (almost certainly) *use* the `write` system call, at least on a system like Linux that has such a thing, and it normally does pretty similar things, but it's still a separate thing of its own.

Linux will, however, pre-open standard input, standard output and standard error streams for your process. To write to the screen, you'd normally use `write` (i.e., the one that is a system call) to write to stream number `1` or stream number `2` (which are standard output and standard error respectively).

If you need to write to the screen even if those are re-directed, you'd normally open a stream to `/dev/tty` and (again) use `write` to write to it:

```c
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main() { 
    char msg[] = "hello\n";

    int fd = open("/dev/tty", O_WRONLY);
    write(fd, msg, sizeof(msg));
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 29):

A system call is a service provided by Linux kernel. In C programming, functions are defined in libc which provide a wrapper for many system calls.  The function call [`write()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/write) is one of these system calls.

The first argument passed to [`write()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/write) is the file descriptor to write to.  The symbolic constants `STDERR_FILENO`, `STDIN_FILENO`, and `STDOUT_FILENO` are respectively defined to **2**, **0**, and **1** in [**unistd.h**](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/unistd.h.html).  You want to write to either **STDOUT_FILENO** or **STDERR_FILENO**.

```
const char msg[] = "Hello World!";
write(STDOUT_FILENO, msg, sizeof(msg)-1);
```

---

You can alternatively use the [`syscall()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/syscall) function to perform an indirrect system call by specifying the function number defined in **syscall.h** or **unistd.h**.  Using this method, you can guarantee that you are only using system calls.  You may find [*The Linux System Call Quick Refernence*](http://www.digilife.be/quickreferences/QRC/LINUX%20System%20Call%20Quick%20Reference.pdf) (PDF Link) to be helpful.

```
/* 4 is the system call number for write() */
const char msg[] = "Hello World!";
syscall(4, STDOUT_FILENO, msg, sizeof(msg)-1);
```

Comment: Strange, but `syscall(4...)` did not work for me, but `syscall(1, 0, "12345\n", 6);` did work.

Comment: @exebook 4 is for Mac, 1 is for Linux

Comment: Link to syscall reference PDF broken. An imperfect substitute might be: https://syscalls.kernelgrok.com/

Answer (score 4):

```
#include <unistd.h>
/* ... */
const char msg[] = "Hello world";
write( STDOUT_FILENO, msg, sizeof( msg ) - 1 );
```

First argument is the file descriptor for `STDOUT` (usually `1`), the second is the buffer to write from, third is the size of the text in the buffer (`-1` is to not print zero terminator).

Answer (score 3):

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE         /* See feature_test_macros(7) */    
#include <unistd.h> // For open, close, read, write, fsync
#include <sys/syscall.h>  //For SYSCALL id __NR_xxx

//Method 1 : API    
write(1,"Writing via API\n",\
        strlen("Writing via API\n") ); 
fsync(1);
//Method 2  : Via syscall id
const char msg[] = "Hello World! via Syscall\n";
syscall(__NR_write, STDOUT_FILENO, msg, sizeof(msg)-1);     
syscall(__NR_fsync, STDOUT_FILENO );    // fsync(STDOUT_FILENO);
```

Answer (score -3):

Your reference is incorrect. It's part of C++ and has nothing to do with your assignment. The correct reference is http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/write.html